# Position DIV elements horizontally (CSS & HTML)

Tags: html, css, hover

I have been trying to create a six button navigation system using images. Each image is 159x159px (though, this may change). The page width currently is 1024, allowing for 10px gaps between the images. The issue comes up when I try to position the images horiztonally and have a div over each of them, my code is as follows:

```css
.STRAND-container {
 /* Colour Strands Container */
  background-color: #333;
 /* Size of Strands Container */
  width: 1024px;
  height: 179px;
 /* Position Strands Container */
  margin: auto;
}

.STRAND-container img {
 /* Size of Strands */
  width: 159px;
  height: 159px;
 /* Space Boxes Properly */
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
 /* Layer Position */
  z-index: 1;
}

.STRAND-container ul,li {
 /* Hide Bullet Points */
 list-style: none;
 /* Position Normally */
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.STRAND-text {
 width: 159px;
 height: 159px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #000;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px;
}

.STRAND-text hr {
 width: 80%;
}

.STRAND-text:hover {
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="STRAND-container">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="STRAND-text">
     <h1>Strand</h1>
     <hr>
     <h2>Text</h2>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="STRAND-text">
     
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="STRAND-text">
     <h1>Strand</h1>
     <hr>
     <h2>Text</h2> 
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="STRAND-text">
     <h1>Strand</h1>
     <hr>
     <h2>Text</h2> 
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="STRAND-text">
     <h1>Strand</h1>
     <hr>
     <h2>Text</h2>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <div class="STRAND-text">
     <h1>Strand</h1>
     <hr>
     <h2>Text</h2>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have a feeling it is going to use some kind of position tag, however I've tried a few different things- none worked. Basically, I wish for each div to float over the top of the images and when hovered over they change to whatever styles are put into the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `position: relative` and `float: left` to the `<li>` tags.
2. Remove the `float: left` from the `<img>`.
3. Add `top: 0` to the `.STRAND-text`

I personally would change the `float: left` in step 1 into a `display: inline-block`. But in that case you also need to make sure that there is no whitespace between the `</li>` and the next `<li>` as otherwise you'll get some additional space (probably about 4px) between them.

```css
.STRAND-container {
  /* Colour Strands Container */
  background-color: #333;
  /* Size of Strands Container */
  width: 1024px;
  height: 179px;
  /* Position Strands Container */
  margin: auto;
}
.STRAND-container img {
  /* Size of Strands */
  width: 159px;
  height: 159px;
  /* Space Boxes Properly */
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  /* Layer Position */
  z-index: 1;
}
.STRAND-container ul,
li {
  /* Hide Bullet Points */
  list-style: none;
  /* Position Normally */
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.STRAND-container li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.STRAND-text {
  width: 159px;
  height: 159px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  top: 0;
}
.STRAND-text hr {
  width: 80%;
}
.STRAND-text:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="STRAND-container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <div class="STRAND-text">
          <h1>Strand</h1>
          <hr>
          <h2>Text</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <div class="STRAND-text">

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <div class="STRAND-text">
          <h1>Strand</h1>
          <hr>
          <h2>Text</h2> 
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <div class="STRAND-text">
          <h1>Strand</h1>
          <hr>
          <h2>Text</h2> 
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <div class="STRAND-text">
          <h1>Strand</h1>
          <hr>
          <h2>Text</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <div class="STRAND-text">
          <h1>Strand</h1>
          <hr>
          <h2>Text</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew something would have to be done with a position tag... are you able to explain what (position: relative) actually does? I've tried to understand it on other sites- would you be able to explain or point me towards a good explanation.

Comment: You're welcome! `position: relative` makes the element be position normally but allows you to use for example `left: 10px` to nudge it `10px` to the right.

In this case however it isn't used for that. It's used to give the `position: absolute` an element to relate to. The `position: absolute` and `top: 0` makes the `.STRAND-text` be positioned zero pixels from the top of its _closest positioned ancestor_. The `position: relative` makes the `<li>` this closest positioned element.

I think both http://learnlayout.com/ and http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/ might be a good tutorial